# php/MySQL Conditional IF ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Multiple Cells in Row

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to update 3 cells of a row on duplicate using the code below. The first part of the on duplicate works fine, checks if the user exists and only updates if the score is higher, however, the second two statements update regardless of the score being higher or not, they don't appear to be included inside the conditional IF statememnt.

```
// This query checks if a user exists and either enters or updates based on high score 
    $date_entered  = date('Y-m-d h:i:s');
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `hkhwa_entries` (player_id, name, week_no, score, date_entered, game_time) 
        VALUES ('$player_id', '$name', '$week_no', '$score', '$date_entered', '$gametime')
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score = if(VALUES(score) > score, VALUES(score), score), date_entered = '$date_entered', game_time = '$gametime'");
```

I have tried the following code but it just breaks the query altogether.

Any help greatly appreciated.

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `entries` (player_id, name, week_no, score, date_entered, game_time) 
    VALUES ('$player_id', '$name', '$week_no', '$score', '$date_entered', '$game_time')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score = if(VALUES(score) > score, VALUES(score), score), 
        date_entered = if(VALUES(score) > score, VALUES(score), score, '$date_entered'), 
        game_time = if(VALUES(score) > score, '$game_time'");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify the IF also for the other two assignments:

```
INSERT INTO hkhwa_entries
     (player_id, name, week_no, score, date_entered, game_time)

VALUES
     ('$player_id', '$name', '$week_no', '$score', '$date_entered', '$gametime')

ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
     score = IF(VALUES(score) > score, VALUES(score), score),
     date_entered = IF(VALUES(score) > score, VALUES(date_entered), date_entered),
     game_time = IF(VALUES(score) > score, VALUES(game_time), game_time)
```

The second version you provided has syntax errors

Answer (score 0):

@user1903887 Try this

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `hkhwa_entries` (player_id, name, week_no, score, date_entered, game_time) 
        VALUES ('$player_id', '$name', '$week_no', '$score', '$date_entered', '$gametime') 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE score = if(VALUES(score) > '$score', VALUES(score),'$score'), 
        date_entered = if(VALUES(score) > '$score', VALUES(date_entered),'$date_entered'), 
        game_time = IF(VALUES(score) > '$score', VALUES(game_time), '$gametime');
```

date_entered = if(VALUES(score) > score, VALUES(score), **score,** '$date_entered')

You use extra `score,` in `date_entered`.

Comment: Thanks for the help Guys, unfortunately neither solution worked.

Comment: What does happen when you try the solution I suggested? It should work fine. What values does data takes after that?

Comment: Hi Blazeag, You are right, it works perfectly when I run it in the SQL window in phpMyAdmin. Doesn't seem to like the way I am wrapping it in php :)